# What is the difference between calling a function with and without parameters?

Tags: java

Imagine I have two functions:

I have a global variable `string username`, the value of which i'm getting from a text field.

```
public void sample_function() {

    // initialize connection, prepared Stmnt and resultset.
    String query="select id from test_table where name=?";
    pst = c.prepareStatement(query);
    pst.setString(1, username); 
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    if(!rs.next()) 
    {
        // something
    }
    else
    {
        do{
            // something

        }while(rs.next());
    }
}
```

and whenever i want to call execute this code block, i just use `sample_function();` This works well. I have seen some code where there is String passed as argument, like

```
public void sample_function(String username) {

    // initialize connection, prepared Stmnt and resultset.
    String query="select id from test_table where name=?";
    pst = c.prepareStatement(query);
    pst.setString(1, username); 
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    if(!rs.next()) 
    {
        // something
    }
    else
    {
        do{
            // something

        }while(rs.next());
    }
}
```

and the function is getting called with `sample_function(username);`.

My questions are:

1. When the query is getting the required input from the textfield, why pass an argument in the first place.
2. If this is the way to write a function, why is sample_function() working as fine as sample_function(username)
3. What are the use cases where we should pass parameters / arguments and when just to use () empty parenthesis

Comment: This is such a general question, like why not move other parameters to variables, why not separate the function into two functions of creating the statement and then reading the result set elsewhere. It's up to you what design works best in your particular class/application.

Comment: Using parameters makes a function more thread-safe.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having functions which take parameters allows you to execute the same function with different data.

Imagine you want to use this function to not just execute code for one username, but for three usernames in a row. How would the code which calls the function look?

With parameters, it would look like this:

```
sampleFunction("User One")
sampleFunction("User Two")
sampleFunction("User Three")
```

But when the function uses a global variable as input, then the code would look a lot more awkward:

```
username = "User One"
sampleFunction()
username = "User Two"
sampleFunction()
username = "User Three"
sampleFunction()
```

This code is not just more ugly, it is also a lot harder to understand.

Think of your teammates who would like to uses your function from their code (remember, software is usually developed in teams). How would they know that they need to set a global variable `username` to some meaningful value before calling this function? Yes, they could look it up in your documentation (if you wrote one) or ask you (if you have time for that). But with function parameters, the development environment will usually tell them "Hey, this function wants a `String username` as input and you didn't give it one". <sub>(might depend on the language, though. For example, in JavaScript all function parameters are optional, so forgetting parameters is syntactically correct even if it might lead to unexpected behavior at runtime)</sub>

And how about the person reading this code and trying to understand how it works? They would have to guess that setting `username` to some value is somehow related to calling `sampleFunction` later. In this particular example it's still kind of obvious. But in a real program, these two steps might happen several lines apart or even in different sourcecode files. So the dependence of the `sampleFunction` on the `username` global variable isn't immediately obvious.

For these reasons it's usually a good idea to pass any information a function needs as parameters instead of storing it in global variables which are then read by the function.

Comment: Really helpful examples philip and @Yomna Hesham. I'm begining to learn and this of great help to understand better. You are correct, i've been using sample_function1(username1) , sample_function2(username2) etc. I wont hereafter!

Answer (score 1):

It's just a design decision not more to make your code clean, reusable and well-structured, based upon the usage.

I give you some examples:

**Example 1:**

If the `username` is **used in many methods in your class**, it's better to make it a **class property** than to pass it as an argument to each method, so that it become **global or shared** with all of them.

On the other hand, if the `username` is used **only** by `sample_function()`, there's no need to make it a class property and make the class messy and ugly with unuseful variables, especially if it's not meaningful for the class to have a property called `username`.

**Example 2:**

Let's consider `sample_function()` is just a search method and is called `searchByUsername()`. For this method to be **readable and meaningfull**, it should take the `username` as an argument, also to be **loosly coupled** to its class, espectially if the class is a `repository`.

**Example 3:**

You can decide according to where the `username`'s value is set from the input field and when `sample_function()` is called. If there's a search button and when the user clicks it, **you should read the `username` value from the text field then call `sample_function()`**, `sample_function()` should take the `username` as an **argument** as the `username` here is **local** within the button function and there's no need to pass it to a global variable and reread it in `sample_function()`.

But if `sample_function()` is called in a **place other than** that `username` value is set in, it's better to save the `username` in a **global** variable, so that it can be **accessable** in `sample_function()`

***... And more and more examples***